# Which command will help me figure out, my base Physical volume that I am residing on?

Tags: unix, command, device, hard-drive, lvm

Is there a way, I can figure out the base physical device, that I am residing on. For example say, physical devices, which cannot be removed/edited/modified....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, `lvdisplay --maps` does what you're looking for. It reports where each part of a logical volume resides.

Comment: Yeah I got that yesterday after searching so hard..... Thats how I am using it right now. Thanks.........

Comment: Also, I need to learn about devices, mapping and stuff.... if you know any material related to it, feel free to post..... Thanks..........

Comment: You mean like, how LVM chooses which physical volumes to use for allocating space to an LV and how it breaks the LV into multiple mappings? I don't know of any references because I don't really know or care how it does it. For me it just does its job well.